# NumPy - Wrap values around arbitrary boundaries

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `x` whose values are contained within `[a, b]` (`a` inclusive, `b` exclusive). Now I want to compute `x + y` (for random `y`) such that `x + y` is still contained within `[a, b]` by wrapping the resulting values around the left or right boundary (whichever is crossed).

Since an example is worth a thousand words:

```
>>> a, b = -5, 5
>>> x = np.array([-4, -2, 0, 2, 4])
>>> wrap(x, 3)  # Compute x + 3.
[-1, 1, 3, -5, -3]
>>> wrap(x, -3)  # Compute x - 3.
[3, -5, -3, -1, 1]
```

I came up with the following implementation but it's not completely satisfactory.

```
def wrap(x, y):
    if y > 0:
        return (x - a + y) % (b - a) + a
    elif y < 0:
        return (x - b + y) % (a - b) + b
    else:
        return x
```

1. This function doesn't get the inclusive / exclusive boundary conditions right; for `wrap(x, -3)` it returns `array([ 3,  5, -3, -1,  1])` while `5` should be `-5`. I'm not sure how to include this functionality.
2. Also the explicit `if` clause looks somewhat artificial and I'm wondering whether it can be handled in a more general way (minor issue).

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem?

Comment: I suppose `a < b`?

Comment: @user202729 Yes `a < b` is assumed though they can take on arbitrary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "wrapping", I suppose that the result should be congruent to `x+y` mod `b-a`. (note that `b-a` is the "window size" in this case)

Consider the special case `a==0`. We have:

```
def wrap(x, y):
    return (x + y) % b
```

Straightforward, right? Note that `%` in Python is floor-modulo -- the sign of result is always the same as the sign of the divisor. So the result will lie in `[0..b[`.

In the more general case:

```
def wrap(x, y):
    return (x + y - a) % (b-a) + a
```

It's straightforward to prove that the return value is congruent to `x+y` mod `b-a`.

Also note that this is the first case in OP's code. It is valid for all values of `y`.

---

However, if `x` is an numpy array, this would perform `len(x)` `%` operations, which may be slow. So instead, it's possible to do the following:

```
def wrap2(x, y):
    y %= b - a
    x = x + y
    return x - (b-a)*(x >= b)
```

It should be faster. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xC8IwEIX3/IpbhERjaRUXJQ6Cow6Cs1xoxEKThjRi8utrqq2IYIYLd/e@e89Gf2vMsuuOl@P5sNufxCLvHyGlusLDoS1o4JEjl2wNTvm7M0DDLM6RTahMdYYf6eJLGicibTdBJO1m4ML8RUxp2ArJCKm0bZwHc9c2ArZgLAnC2MyhKRv9@irjac6LnI/5GMG2VYmiY7gV7wUMhPiEGEYsw7qmyejqGg2@0qryMJi@O2Jd7/BuaI1alrj@ucL7gFI5scrTyb9E8Y/ouic)

Explanation:

- `y %= b-a`: Reduce `y` to range `[0..b-a[`. This will not affect the result.
- `x = x + y`: Add `y` to `x`. After this step `x` will contain the correct value, modulo `b-a`. All values in `x` should be in range `[a..b+(b-a)[`.
- `x - (b-a)*(x >= b)`: `(x >= b)` (if interpreted as an integer) evaluates to `1` if `x >= b`, and `0` otherwise. Subtracting that multiply `b-a` from `x` will subtract `b-a` from all values `>= b`, and keep those `< b` intact.

Comment: Even faster than David's solution, simplified using this answer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9Bi8MgEIXv/govBW1NSRN6aXEPhR63h4U9LaWMxLKBaMRYVn99VtMklIUc1oMy4/vemzHBfbe67PvL7fL5fjp/8CJPB6FK3vGPBbMjngUGTNADttI9rMbEb0IGdEVEvDcwS4sXaVjx@Hv0PGqP/su/cXHNhtZo4mesXMImZTYErUkyoQjVyrTWYf1QJmDosDbIc222FnTVquGptSM52@VsWosi6DoZKTLttGdJQDHn8@xji26haUgMuttWYVcrWTs8hj4rZGxKeBakASUqOPwxZmlAIS3f59FykSj@TZRLRN//Ag "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: This is faster since it is more vectorized. Nice work. Does take some explaining though to process it. This is exactly what numpy is for though. You can take a question and transform it into fast code through using equivalent math.

Comment: @user202729 Looks like I was not completely aware of what the `mod` operator does in Python. Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input array is already within the range [a,b), then we can rewrite `wrap` as the following function;

```
def wrap(x,y,a,b):
    if y > 0:
        x += y
        x[x >=b] -= (b-a)
    elif y < 0:
        x += y
        x[x < a] += (b-a)
    return x
```

Comment: Of course not, why would you add more than the range of (a,b) to x? You should always mod it first. You asked about wrapping values, not wrapping multiple times.